# How can i extract failure condition in Twisted

Tags: twisted

In my program i have method that handles all errors. Something like this

```
def _processError(self, failure):
    ''' Process various errors '''
    if isinstance(failure, Failure):
        error = failure.trap(SASLAuthError, StanzaError)
        if error == SASLAuthError:
            self.notifyObservers(error = 'authorization')
        elif error == StanzaError:
            self.notifyObservers(error = 'subscription')
```

I need to implement more specific information about failures (condition). One way is to call getErrorMessage and parse a string . But this is not very good because of possibility of changing error format in Twisted. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: sorry for bad explanation. I already solved this problem. Condition can be taken by failure.value.condition

Comment: Got a workable code for your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181990/twisted-how-to-get-error-parameters-from-failure) But I don't know is it really the right-way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use callback and errback chains (with the help [twisted.internet.defer](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html) module) to handle error conditions while programming with twisted.